# Stop MessageListenerContainer across RabbitMQ clusters

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

We have created RabbitMQ cluster on two separate machines and message producer sends messages to RabbitMQ Load balancer. Message consumers also connecting to RabbitMQ load balancer.

Now, we want Listeners of specific queues to pause for some time. I see that ListenerContainer's stop() method can be helpful in this case. But I want to know if this will stop containers on both RabbitMQ instances.

Please note that, I cannot test this on DEV/SIT as clustering is available in UAT and PROD only.

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to call ListenerContainer's stop() method in clustered environment. It stopped processing messages from both RabbitMQ instances. So the answer is 'Yes' !